# Bind button in DataTemplate C#

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to bind a button in a DataTemplate that is being used by a collection view.
This is my button inside the DataTemplate, and I want to bind it to a command in "DetailDayPageViewModel".

```
        Button viewComment = new Button()
        {
            TextColor = Color.DodgerBlue,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
            FontSize = 16
        };
        // this binding does not work
        viewComment.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, nameof(DetailDayPageViewModel.ViewComment));
```

Comment: Thank you for changing it to the comments, much appreciated. Regarding your query you need to use the relative binding concept to map to the Parent's BindingContext. I'll try to send you code to acheive this

Comment: Absolutely! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `RelativeBinding` for binding values of Page's BindingContext to property inside DataTemplate.

There are two ways to do this:

1: Binding through the ViewModel. ReltiveBinding of Mode `FindAncestorBindingContext`

```cs
public class ItemView : Grid
{
    public ItemView()
    {
        Button clickButton = new Button() { Text = "Hi there" };
        clickButton.SetBinding(
            Button.CommandProperty,
            new Binding(
                "ItemClickCommand",
                source: new RelativeBindingSource(
                    RelativeBindingSourceMode.FindAncestorBindingContext,
                    typeof(ViewModel))
                ));

        this.Children.Add(clickButton);
    }
}
```

2: Binding through the Parent view `BindingContext`:

```cs
public class ItemView : Grid
{
    public ItemView()
    {
        Button clickButton = new Button() { Text = "Hi there" };
        clickButton.SetBinding(
            Button.CommandProperty,
            new Binding(
                "BindingContext.ItemClickCommand",
                source: new RelativeBindingSource(
                    RelativeBindingSourceMode.FindAncestor,
                    typeof(CollectionView))
                ));

        this.Children.Add(clickButton);
    }
}
```

Please do check and see if it helps!! Comment for any queries.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! Which one is best to use? or is it just personal preference?

Comment: It is a personal preference. I would suggest using FindAncestor as the Parent can be same for a View(ex: CollectionView), you can use it in any page in the App within CollectionView. Other than that it's a personal preference. @JonathanK

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take a look to this sample:

[TestBinding](https://github.com/acaliaro/TestBindingWithListView/blob/master/TestBinding/MyPage.cs)

It refers to a ListView, but it should be applicated to a CollectionView.

You need to set the the "source":

```
        TapGestureRecognizer tgrUpDown2 = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        tgrUpDown2.SetBinding(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandProperty, new Binding("BindingContext.UpDown2Command", source: this));
        tgrUpDown2.SetBinding(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandParameterProperty, ".");
```

then in your Model, you have the "parameter" passend...

```
  this.UpDown2Command = new Command(async (object obj) =>
        {

            try
            {
                if (_isTapped)
                    return;

                if (obj != null)
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Obj is not null");
                else
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Obj IS null");


                _isTapped = true;

                int idx = List.IndexOf((Model)obj);

                List[idx].Checked1 = !List[idx].Checked1;

                _isTapped = false;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _isTapped = false;
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Attention", ex.Message, "Ok");
            }
        });
```

This is a useful link I have found some years ago:

[listview-in-xamarin-forms-in-mvvm](https://techsolutions2017.blogspot.com/2017/01/listview-in-xamarin-forms-in-mvvm.html#comment-form)

If you want a "class" to define your ViewCell, you can assign the class in this way:

```
        lv.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
        {
            return new MyViewCell(lv);
        });
```

Where MyViewCell is something like:

```
    class MyViewCell : ViewCell
    {

        public MyViewCell(ListView lv)
        {
            StackLayout slView = new StackLayout();
            slView.SetBinding(StackLayout.BackgroundColorProperty, "BackgroundColor");

            Label lDesc = new Label();
            lDesc.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Description", stringFormat: "DESCRIPTION: {0}");
            lDesc.SetBinding(Label.TextColorProperty, "TextColor");

            // LABEL QTY
            TapGestureRecognizer tgrQty = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            tgrQty.SetBinding(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandProperty, new Binding("BindingContext.QtyCommand", source: lv));
            tgrQty.SetBinding(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandParameterProperty, ".");
```

....
   ....

```
            View = slView;

        }

    }
```

You can pass "ListView" in the constructor so you can use it in "source" binding property.

Comment: Thank you this worked:
SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, new Binding("BindingContext.ViewComment", source: this));

But it did not work if I put the DataTemplate in a separate class so I tried to change the binding to:
viewComment.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, new Binding(nameof(DetailDayPageViewModel.ViewComment), source: nameof(DetailDayPage)));

But it did not work, do you know how to make the binding work when the DataTemplate is in another class other than in the page class?

Comment: updated my response and the project on github: https://github.com/acaliaro/TestBindingWithListView